# How animate a card on entry in a tinder-like card view?

Tags: android, animation, android-cardview

I have implemented a tinder like card view for my project. It is basically a custom view which extends the AdapterView. I want to add a grow animation (increase size) on the top card in the view. I have tried OnItemSelectedListener, adding animations in the getView method of the adapter, onFocusChageListener etc., but none have worked for me. Can someone suggest a way around for this?

Comment: Have you taken a look at Google's material design? https://developer.android.com/training/material/lists-cards.html

Comment: Thanks, but I finally figured it out. Had to be done through the getView() method of the adapter only.